# $ A: \{\frac{m^2n^3 + 3m^2n^2+2mn^3+6mn^2}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}, n, m \in \mathbb{N} \}$ Got limitation need superemum.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I need to find supremum of:

$$ A: \{\frac{m^2n^3 + 3m^2n^2+2mn^3+6mn^2}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}, n, m \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

I found out that:

$$ \frac{m^2n^3 + 3m^2n^2+2mn^3+6mn^2}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2} = \frac{m^2(n^3 + 3n^2) + 2m(n^3+3n^2)}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}= \frac{(m^2+2m)(n^3 + 3n^2)}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}$$

$$\frac{(m^2+2m)(n^3 + 3n^2)}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}= \frac{\sqrt{(m^2+2m)^2(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}$$
And from inequality of means (AM - GM) I know that:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(m^2+2m)^2(n^3 + 3n^2)^2}}{(m^2 + 2m)^2+(n^3 + 3n^2)^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore I found a limitation of my set A. Now I need a sequence of elements belonging in $A$ that would be convergent to $\frac{1}{2}$. That is the part I can't do myself.

From graph I know that if I take $m = n$ then for $n \in [1 ; \infty)$ I get decreasing function and for that function $\frac{1}{2}$ is reached by $n < 1$. A maximal value of that function for $n \in  [1 ; \infty)$ is equal to $\frac{12}{25}$ and is reached by $n = 1$. But that is not a solution.

There is no ANY fact that would legitimise value $\frac{12}{25}$ as the supremum of that set since there always might by something bigger if $n \neq m$.

What I need is a prove that in the supremum of set $A$: $m = n$ (I don't know why that would be the case) or that there is a bigger value reached for $n$ and $m$ that are not equal.

It might be important to add that I can not use integrals nor derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pick a sub-sequence of $A$ in the following fashion: $n=1, 2, \cdots, $, and $m$ depends on $n$ via $m=\lfloor \sqrt{a_n+1} \rfloor$.

Define $a_n = n^3+3n^2, b_m=m^2+2m=(m+1)^2-1=\lfloor\sqrt{a_n+1}+1 \rfloor^2-1$. Then $\frac{a_n b_m}{a_n^2+b_m^2} \in A$ and we will prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n b_m}{a_n^2+b_m^2} \to \frac 12.$

Note that $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x, \forall x$, then

$$a_n=(\sqrt{a_n+1})^2-1 < \lfloor \sqrt{a_n+1}+1\rfloor^2-1 \le (\sqrt{a_n+1}+1)^2-1 \\
\implies 1 < \frac{b_m}{a_n} \le \frac{(\sqrt{a_n+1}+1)^2-1}{a_n} = 1 + \frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{2\sqrt{a_n+1}}{a_n}$$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = 1 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n b_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2} = \frac 12. \blacksquare$

Comment: I think that there is an error in the 2nd line. $m^2+2m+1 \neq (m+1)^2-1$

Comment: Yes fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it at all to be honest. Could you write some more? For example, why do you define $m(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{a_n+1} \rfloor$? Is that even correct?

Comment: Huh? Why not?  $(\sqrt{a_n+1})^2-1 = a_n+1-1=a_n$.

Comment: Ok, I see that now, but how on earth did you get the idea to define $m$ exactly like that?

Comment: $m$ is defined as such so that $m^2+2m$ is as close to $n^3+3n^2$ as possible, meaning $a_n$ and $b_m$ are very close so that $a_n b_m/(a_n^2+b_m^2)$ is close to $1/2$.

Comment: $xy/(x^2+y^2) \le 1/2$, when $x$ is close enough to $y$ then $xy/(x^2+y^2)$ is close enough to $1/2$.

Comment: We want $m^2 < n^3 + 3n^2+1 < (m+1)^2$ that's why.

Comment: Ok, so could you just show me how did you get that $m=\lfloor \sqrt{a_n+1} \rfloor$ is a as close as possible?

Comment: $m^2+2m \approx n^3+3n^2 \implies (m+1)^2 \approx n^3+3n^2+1 = a_n+1 \implies m+1 \approx \sqrt{a_n+1}$.

Comment: And why do you take the floor and not $-1$ when defining m?

Comment: Either floor or ceiling will do. Close enough

Comment: Ok, and if you did $m + 1 \approx \sqrt{a_n + 1} \implies m \approx \sqrt{a_n + 1} -1$ would it work? Because that floor when I can just substract 1 on both sides looks strange to me.

Comment: If you want a sub-sequence from $A$ then you can't because $m$ is an integer, that's why you need to round $\sqrt{a_n+1}$ up or down. Working with floor/ceiling function isn't hard once you get used to it.

Comment: I think I get it now, thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but something you could try. You could still use differentiation. Replace the function with a continuous one,
$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2y^3+3x^2y^2+2xy^3+6xy^2}{(x^2+2x)^2+(y^3+3y^2)^2},$$
Calculate $\max_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)$. Then calculate the values near it which correspond to integers and pick amongst them.

PS:- Please try to make the questions a little less "wordy". At least please try to keep that in mind for all future posts.

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot an addition sign in the denominator.

Comment: Okay, the idea still remains the same. I have updated my answer.